# How to set up a Selenium Python environment for Firefox?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, automation, selenium-firefoxdriver

How can I set up a Selenium Python environment for Firefox?

I am using Firefox 50, Selenium 3, Python 3.5. I tried with many things binary and copying the geckodriver in the environment variable *PATH*, etc.

Comment: 1. Download and install Firefox on your machine (if you haven't done so already). 2. Run `pip install selenium` in a command line (if you haven't done so already). 3. Write your code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to develop in Python, using the Selenium library and work with the Firefox webdriver.

1. Install Python (Python 3 already contains pip)
2. Install Selenium (`pip install selenium` *or* some IDEs like [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyCharm) propose to install libraries, just import Selenium)
3. Download [Mozilla webdriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)
4. Enjoy!

Answer (score 25):

The testing machine should have Selenium v. 3.0.2, Firefox v. 51.0.1 (latest version) and geckodriver v. 0.14. If you are using Linux, please do the following steps:

[Look up the [latest release on GitHub](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/) ([or from the API](https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/latest)) and replace the wget link with that. Downloading and installing an outdating release may result in "buggy" behaviour.]

```
apt-get update
apt-get install firefox
pip3 install selenium==3.0.2
wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/vX.XX.0/geckodriver-vX.XX.0-linuxXX.tar.gz -O /tmp/geckodriver.tar.gz \
  && tar -C /opt -xzf /tmp/geckodriver.tar.gz \
  && chmod 755 /opt/geckodriver \
  && ln -fs /opt/geckodriver /usr/bin/geckodriver \
  && ln -fs /opt/geckodriver /usr/local/bin/geckodriver
```

Select the version for your operating system from the available compressed pre-built binaries.

Here is an example to run:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://google.com')
print(driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

1. In Windows install Python from: https://www.python.org/downloads/
2. Then run pip install from the command line: `pip install selenium`
3. Download the Gecko/Chrome/Internet Explorer driver and add the driver.exe path to the PATH environment variable. So the need to set up the path while running Selenium driver.Firefox() / driver.Chrome() method.

Answer (score 1):

Since **Selenium 4.6.0**, you don't need to manually install **Selenium Manager(webdriver-manager)** as shown below because it is already included in Selenium according to [the blog](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/selenium-4-6-0-released/):

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

And, since **Selenium 4.11.0**, the code below is basically enough because [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/) can automatically discover your browser version installed in your machine, then can automatically download the proper driver version for it according to [the blog](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/whats-new-in-selenium-manager-with-selenium-4.11.0/):

```py
from selenium import webdriver

firefox_driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

And, the examples below can test Django Admin with Firefox, [Selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium), [pytest-django](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django) and [Django](https://github.com/django/django). *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58461862/how-to-run-my-python-selenium-scripts-using-browser/77029091#77029091) explains how to test Django Admin with multiple Headless browsers(Chrome, Microsoft Edge and Firefox), Selenium, pytest-django and Django:

```py
# "tests/test_1.py"

import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def firefox_driver_init(request):
    firefox_driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    request.cls.driver = firefox_driver
    yield
    firefox_driver.close()

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("firefox_driver_init")
class Test_URL_Firefox(LiveServerTestCase):
    def test_open_url(self):
        self.driver.get(("%s%s" % (self.live_server_url, "/admin/")))
        assert "Log in | Django site admin" in self.driver.title
```

Or:

```py
# "tests/conftest.py"

import pytest
from selenium import webdriver

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def firefox_driver_init(request):
    firefox_driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    request.cls.driver = firefox_driver
    yield
    firefox_driver.close()
```

```py
# "tests/test_1.py"

import pytest
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("firefox_driver_init")
class Test_URL_Firefox(LiveServerTestCase):
    def test_open_url(self):
        self.driver.get(("%s%s" % (self.live_server_url, "/admin/")))
        assert "Log in | Django site admin" in self.driver.title
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Ubuntu and the latest firefox. You may find some issues since firefox is bundled now in snap.

To resolve the issue with driver not being able to connect to the firefox, you will need to use driver bundled with snap.

I bundled an ready to go example here: https://github.com/beliaev-maksim/firefox-selenium

However, for quick access here is the content of conftest.py for quickly setup a driver fixture

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def driver(request):
    """Set up webdriver fixture."""
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

    service = Service(executable_path="firefox.geckodriver")
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, service=service)
    driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    yield driver
    driver.quit()
```