# How to run my python selenium scripts using browser?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, selenium-webdriver, browser

I've written python selenium script on Django framework. Now I have no clue how can I run the test case using browser. I can execute the test case through terminal. Now I need to execute the same test case through browser. Like with URL I need to start executing the test case.

Comment: Do you mean you need the tests to start when you access a certain URL? or do you want the tests to actually open a browser window and show you what the tests are doing?

Comment: Yes, I mean tests to start when I access a browser or when I click a button a button on that URL webpage

Comment: You need to run a webserver and serve that webpage with the button you want to click. Check a web framework like Django or Flask and start from there.  https://www.djangoproject.com/start/ or https://palletsprojects.com/p/flask/

Comment: Thank you devbob for your reply and time. But I have already build an project name blog in that I have users app and in that test.py file resides. Now how I can point to the file on web brower to start?

Comment: I suggest this resource: [Obey the Testing Goat](https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/chapter_01.html). This looks like a fit in your requirements (i.e., run a script so it shows a webpage and test your Django app functionally).

Comment: Also note: you may need to discern your tests between functional (i.e., how does the interface work) and unit (i.e., is each method/route/model working as expected).

Answer (score 0):

You can test with [pytest-django](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django) and [selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium) in Django.

First, `pytest-django` and `selenium` as shown below:

```
pip install pytest-django && pip install selenium
```

Then, create [pytest.ini](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.3.x/reference/customize.html#pytest-ini) and [conftest.py](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#conftest-py-sharing-fixtures-across-multiple-files), `test_1.py` and `__init__.py`(Empty file) in `tests` folder as shown below. *`pytest.ini` should be put in the root directory of `django-project` folder and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466027/what-is-conftest-py-for-in-pytest/77030965#77030965) explains that multiple `conftest.py` can be used:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  └-settings.py
 |-my_app1
 |-my_app2
 |-pytest.ini
 └-tests
    |-__init__.py
    |-conftest.py 
    └-test_1.py
```

Then, set the code below to `pytest.ini`. *I recommend to set `tests` to [testpaths](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#confval-testpaths) because it makes the test faster according to [the doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#confval-testpaths):

```ini
# "pytest.ini"

[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = core.settings
testpaths = tests
```

Now for example, set the code below to `tests/conftest.py` and `tests/test_1.py` to test Django Admin with the multiple headless browsers Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge and Firefox together with Selenium. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77041384/how-to-test-django-with-multiple-broswers-together-with-selenium-to-reduce-the-c/77041385#77041385) explains how to test Django Admin with the multiple browsers Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge and Firefox together with Selenium:

```py
# "tests/conftest.py"

import pytest
from selenium import webdriver

@pytest.fixture(params=["chrome", "edge", "firefox"], scope="class")
def browser_driver_init(request):
    if request.param == "chrome":
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--headless=new")
        web_driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    if request.param == "edge":
        options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--headless=new")
        web_driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options)
    if request.param == "firefox":
        options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
        options.add_argument("-headless")
        web_driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    request.cls.driver = web_driver
    yield
    web_driver.close()
```

```py
# "tests/test_1.py"

import pytest

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("browser_driver_init")
class Test_URL_Browser:
    def test_open_url(self, live_server):
        self.driver.get(("%s%s" % (live_server.url, "/admin/")))
        assert "Log in | Django site admin" in self.driver.title
```

Finally, run the command below:

```
pytest
```