# How to run headless Microsoft Edge with Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-headless, browser-options

With Chrome you can add options when creating the driver. You just do

```py
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH\TO\DRIVER, options=options)
```

But for some reason when trying to do the same with Microsoft Edge

```py
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Edge(PATH\TO\DRIVER, options=options)
```

I get this error below:

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options'

For some reason Edge's driver doesn't accept any other parameters than the file path. Is there any way to run Edge headless and add more options just like in Chrome?

Comment: what version of selenium are you using?

Comment: @Sharmiko Selenium 3.141.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  options = EdgeOptions()
  options.use_chromium = True
  options.add_argument("headless")
  options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
```

Try above code , you have to enable chromium to enable headless

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=python

This works only for new edge chromium not for edge legacy versions . In legacy versions headless is not supported

**Full code**

```
from msedge.selenium_tools import EdgeOptions
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge

# make Edge headless
edge_options = EdgeOptions()
edge_options.use_chromium = True  # if we miss this line, we can't make Edge headless
# A little different from Chrome cause we don't need two lines before 'headless' and 'disable-gpu'
edge_options.add_argument('headless')
edge_options.add_argument('disable-gpu')
driver = Edge(executable_path='youredgedriverpath', options=edge_options)
```

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'AddArgument'`

Comment: It was java code before , added python code and the edge chromium documentation . If you are using edge legacy then you cannot run it in headless

Comment: I running the latest version of edge and still get the same error

Comment: What error , I updated the code could you paste the error

Comment: pip install msedge-selenium-tools , you have to install this read that documentation .

Comment: The fist thing I get is `EdgeOptions is not defined` and then an error saying `AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'add_argument'` Edit: I already installed msedge-tools

Comment: The code now works but I still need to insatiate the driver and I can't add the options as a parameter.

Comment: anyone knows how to do this in NodeJS?

Answer (score 3):

`webdriver.Edge` does not accept any `options` so i switched it to the following:
It worked for me.

```
        # imports
        from selenium import webdriver
        from msedge.selenium_tools import EdgeOptions

        # options
        options = EdgeOptions()
        options.use_chromium = True
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        options.add_argument("disable-gpu")

        browser = webdriver.Chrome(
            executable_path="resources/msedgedriver.exe", options=options)
        browser.get(gen_token)
```

The version of Microsoft Edge that I am using is :

Microsoft Edge
Version 89.0.774.57 (Official build) (64-bit)

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can run headless Microsoft Edge with [Selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium) in Python as shown below:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=new") # Here
driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options)
```

Or:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless=new") # Here
driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options)
```

In addition, the examples below can test Django Admin with headless Microsoft Edge, Selenium, [pytest-django](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django) and [Django](https://github.com/django/django). *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58461862/how-to-run-my-python-selenium-scripts-using-browser/77029091#77029091) explains how to test Django Admin with multiple headless browsers(Chrome, Microsoft Edge and Firefox), Selenium, pytest-django and Djang:

```py
# "tests/test_1.py"

import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def edge_driver_init(request):
    options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless=new")
    edge_driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options)
    request.cls.driver = edge_driver
    yield
    edge_driver.close()

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("edge_driver_init")
class Test_URL_Edge(LiveServerTestCase):
    def test_open_url(self):
        self.driver.get(("%s%s" % (self.live_server_url, "/admin/")))
        assert "Log in | Django site admin" in self.driver.title
```

Or:

```py
# "tests/conftest.py"

import pytest
from selenium import webdriver

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def edge_driver_init(request):
    options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless=new")
    edge_driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options)
    request.cls.driver = edge_driver
    yield
    edge_driver.close()
```

```py
# "tests/test_1.py"

import pytest
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("edge_driver_init")
class Test_URL_Edge(LiveServerTestCase):
    def test_open_url(self):
        self.driver.get(("%s%s" % (self.live_server_url, "/admin/")))
        assert "Log in | Django site admin" in self.driver.title
```

Answer (score -2):

for Edge browser

```
options = EdgeOptions()

options.use_chromium = True

options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')

options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")

wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install(), options=options)

wd.maximize_window()
```

For Edge headless

```
options = EdgeOptions()

options.use_chromium = True

options.add_argument("--headless")

options.add_argument("disable-gpu")

options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')

options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install(), options=options)

wd.maximize_window()
```