# How to work with headless Microsoft Edge with Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-headless

Well, I am working on a project that uses selenium to grab some movie files and download them from the website. Everything is working fine but I don't want to open the browser window and want it to run in the background and show the results in the end without invoking the browser. I have tried many ways but have failed to find out a reliable answer. There are questions related to this on StackOverflow but they are not working for Edge. The answers to other questions tell about adding this line.

```
from selenium.webdriver.Edge.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path="msedgedriver.exe", options=options)
```

But this is not working for me and the following error pop-up.

```
File "movies.pyx", line 11, in init movies
driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path="msedgedriver.exe", options=options)
  TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options'
```

I also have tried seeing many answers to similar questions but nothing works. If anyone knows do answer i will be very thankful to you in advance.

**Well I am using python 3.7.7**

Answer (score 1):

you are using Microsoft Edge webdriver.
the way you are trying make it headless is for chrome webdriver.

```
  options = EdgeOptions()
  options.use_chromium = True
  options.add_argument("headless")
  options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
```

Try above code by importing:

```
from msedge.selenium_tools import EdgeOptions
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge
```

**note :** you have to enable chromium to enable headless.

Comment: Thanks, it has solved the problem. Just one thing I want to point out is that I think you have forgotten to tell about the library that can be done as (pip install msedge-selenium-tools)

Answer (score 0):

It's not directly a solution to the problem, but an alternative, I think you can check this simple library : https://pypi.org/project/activesoup/

> activesoup combines familiar python web capabilities for convenient
> **headless “browsing” functionality**.
> [...] Consider using activesoup when: [...] You need to actively interact
> with some web-page from Python (e.g. **submitting forms, downloading
> files**)

Answer (score 0):

You can run Headless Microsoft Edge with [Selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium) in Python as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65171183/how-to-run-headless-microsoft-edge-with-selenium-in-python/77032907#77032907) explains it with Django examples:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=new") # Here
driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options)
```

Or:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless=new") # Here
driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options)
```