# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options' while using EdgeOptions

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromium, selenium-edgedriver

Hi I trying to run the below code for Edge Driver version Version 90.0.818.42 which is Chromium Based:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from msedge.selenium_tools import EdgeOptions

dirpath = os.getcwd()

edge_driver_path_used = dirpath + r'/features/resources/drivers/msedgedriver.exe'

my_edge_option = EdgeOptions()
my_edge_option.use_chromium = True
my_edge_option.binary_location = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
edge_driver = webdriver.Edge(options=my_edge_option)

edge_driver.get('My URL Here')
```

Upon running this code I am getting the below exception:

```
edge_driver = webdriver.Edge(options=my_edge_option)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options'
```

I don't seem to miss any import, then why am I getting this Exception? Kindly help me out

Answer (score 2):

Seems like here's solution to your question:
[How to run Microsoft Edge headless with Selenium Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65171183/how-to-run-microsoft-edge-headless-with-selenium-python)

```
  options = EdgeOptions()
  options.use_chromium = True
```

install the addition package like:

```
pip install msedge-selenium-tools
```

and initialize driver with:

```
from msedge.selenium_tools import EdgeOptions
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge

# Edge in headless mode
edge_options = EdgeOptions()
edge_options.use_chromium = True
driver = Edge(executable_path='your_driver_path', options=edge_options)
```

Here's official docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=python

Comment: @UmangBhatia pleased to hear it and it's up to you entirely, you should use driver = Edge(executable_path='your_driver_path', options=edge_options)

Comment: thanks, i was using the wrong Edge class. The issue is resolved now

Comment: @UmangBhatia please mark the answer like confirmed, and update question a bit to get the upvote