# TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'firefox_options' error using firefox_options as arguments in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

I'm trying to create a script which downloads a file from a website and for this I want to change the download filepath. When I try to do this with the Firefox options it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'firefox_options'
```

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

options = Options()

options.add_argument("download.default_directory=C:\\Music")
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\\selenium\\geckodriver.exe')
browser.get('https://duckduckgo.com/')
```

Comment: Go through this link and let us know if that helps or not https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67192474/typeerror-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-options-while-using-e

Comment: never versions of Selenium don't use `firefox_options` but `options`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The browser option parameter `firefox_options` was deprecated in [**Selenium 3.8.0**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/4c0404e9580050c488f714885adea712a6f2da0d/py/CHANGES#L368)

> > - Browser option parameters are now standardized across drivers as `options`. `firefox_options`, `chrome_options`, and `ie_options` are now deprecated

Instead you have to use `options` as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("download.default_directory=C:\\Music")
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\\selenium\\geckodriver.exe')
```

Comment: you can also set executable path with service parameter, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76428561/typeerror-webdriver-init-got-multiple-values-for-argument-options) for more info