# TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'options'

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

Error is:

```
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'options'
```

`

The code is:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'/usr/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
```

This is the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-9a7e59e392ae> in <cell line: 6>()
      4 chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
      5 
----> 6 browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'/usr/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'options'
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 54):

This is due to changes in `selenium` `4.10.0`:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e

[image: Changes_in_selenium_4_10_0]

Note that the first argument is no longer `executable_path`, but `options`. (That's why it complains that you're passing it in twice.)

If you want to pass in an `executable_path`, you'll have to use the `service` arg now.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path=r'/usr/bin/chromedriver')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

Comment: If anyone else finds their way here because pyhtml2pdf was affected by this breakage, there's a pull request based on this answer that fixes the problem: https://github.com/kumaF/pyhtml2pdf/pull/2

Comment: Thanks, Michael. Using your suggestion I'm getting: 

WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1

Any thoughts on this

Comment: @OmarSaidLópezTronco That looks like a separate issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49710327/7058266. Could also happen if Chrome isn't installed on that system.

Comment: What about desired_capabilities?

Comment: @ViniCoder Use `options.set_capability(name, value)` instead of `desired_capabilities`.

Comment: Changing 

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)` 

to 

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=webdriver_options)` worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

### #Working solution for selenium driver not working

```py
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
```

## Please cross check if you add .exe at the end of your Chromedriver path

```py
service = Service(executable_path=r"..\chromedriver.exe") 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
```

#It work for me hope selenium version 4.1 chrome 116 latest one

Answer (score 1):

I got this answer from this blog and it worked!
https://nariyoo.com/python-how-to-run-selenium-in-google-colab/

[[Python] How to run selenium in Google Colab](https://nariyoo.com/python-how-to-run-selenium-in-google-colab/)

```
!pip install chromedriver-autoinstaller

import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')

import time
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller

# setup chrome options
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless') # ensure GUI is off
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

# set path to chromedriver as per your configuration
chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()

# set the target URL
url = "put-url-here-to-scrape"

# set up the webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Now you can easily import other selenium library that you need and the driver will be worked. I hope it help!