# TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'options''

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

stackoverflow.com/questions/76428561/typeerror-webdriver-init-got-multiple-values-for-argument-options <--I tried to find a solution here (p.s two attempt).
I tried to find a solution here
In the first attempt 2 or more days ago, everything worked and I continued to work on my program.
But yesterday everything broke and I can't find a solution, I get an error in the second attempt

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common import keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import Frame, Tk, BOTH, Text, Menu, END
from tkinter import filedialog
import csv
import pandas as pd
from docx import Document
from random import choice
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
import datetime
url = 'https://elibrary.ru/'

#1 attempt: everything worked for me here, an error appeared yesterday

#options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
#binary_yandex_driver_file = 'yandexdriver.exe' # path to YandexDriver
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(binary_yandex_driver_file, options=options)
#driver.get(url)
#2attempt
service = Service(executable_path=r'./yandexdriver')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
binary_yandex_driver_file = 'yandexdriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(binary_yandex_driver_file, service=service, options=options)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
original_window = driver.current_window_handle
assert len(driver.window_handles) == 1
```

I use selenium chrome, but for Yandex Browser, github.com/yandex/YandexDriver

Comment: Your easier way out of this connundrum is to downgrade selenium to 4.9.0

Comment: Duplicate. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76432322/7058266 for the solution