# webdriver.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'options'

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[it works on my computer using python from microsoft store but in my laptop using python download from web it has this errol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1HRT.png)
i have import selenium
install web driver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
debugging_address='127.0.1:9848'
web_driver_path='C:\chromederiver.exe'
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", debugging_address)
print(chrome_options)
driver = Chrome(web_driver_path, options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Duplicate, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76432322/7058266