# Python Selenium TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'options'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=2050,2050")
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=chrome_options)
```

when I ever run the code it keeps saying the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-8904e7337232> in <cell line: 6>()
      4 chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
      5 chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
----> 6 driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=chrome_options)

TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'options'
```

can anyone help if possible? I tried the other solution it's not working for some reason

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76428561/typeerror-webdriver-init-got-multiple-values-for-argument-options?rq=2

Comment: No Jesse, I tried it before posting my question, I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: Please post the full error traceback, not just the final line.

Comment: I have just updated it, sorry just noticed that I did not include the full error now it's fixed

Comment: *No Jesse* -- Actually, yes, it DOES answer your question exactly.  The method of calling `webdriver.Chrome` has changed.  The first parameter is now `options`, so you are passing it twice.  If you've actually tried the suggested fix (which I doubt), then please show the code here.

Comment: Lol you got my questions closed and reported, calm down kiddo I am still trying to learn, and yes I did try it out and it's still not working, you could have showed me what I did wrong or advised me rather than crying here