# WebDriver __init()__ got multiple values for arguments 'options'

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code:

```
    options = Options()
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
    options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")
    options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/var/tmp/chrome_user_data")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Elamaran\script.py", line 48, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'options'
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: WebDriver.\_\_init\_\_() got multiple values for argument 'options'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76428561/typeerror-webdriver-init-got-multiple-values-for-argument-options)