# I can't open chrome with a profile

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I try to open a tab with a profile but I get this error

WebDriver.**init**() got multiple values for argument 'options'

````
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions

PATH = "chromedriver.exe"
url = "https://web.whatsapp.com/"
options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir = C:\\Users\\omer\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 1")

Driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH,options=options)
Driver.get(url) ```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: WebDriver.\_\_init\_\_() got multiple values for argument 'options'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76428561/typeerror-webdriver-init-got-multiple-values-for-argument-options)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [Service](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/service/) class now to pass the `executable_path`

Check the below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path="C:/<fullpath>/chromedriver.exe")
url = "https://web.whatsapp.com/"
options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir = C:\\Users\\omer\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 1")

Driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service,options=options)
Driver.get(url)
```