# Version 117.0.5938.150 Selenium Error: 'WebDriver.init() got multiple values for argument 'options' when passing proxies

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

I'm encountering an issue with the latest version of Selenium when trying to pass proxies using SeleniumWire. The error message I'm getting is "WebDriver.init() got multiple values for argument 'options'". Below is my current code:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

user = "fff"
password = "fffff"
endpoint = "fffff:ffffff"

wire_options = {
    "proxy": {
        "http": f"http://{user}:{password}@{endpoint}",
        "https": f"http://{user}:{password}@{endpoint}",
    }
}

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
proxies = wire_options

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options, seleniumwire_options=proxies
)

# Open the website with a new URL for each email
driver.get('https://ff.fff.com/')
```

I'd appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this issue and successfully pass proxies with SeleniumW.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: WebDriver.\_\_init\_\_() got multiple values for argument 'options'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76428561/typeerror-webdriver-init-got-multiple-values-for-argument-options)

Comment: No @Melphin ,  because I am discussing the latest Selenium and ChromeDriver issue.

Comment: I need to pass proxies as well

Answer (score 0):

`Chrome` webdriver doesn't have the `path` parameter in Selenium 4, so `ChromeDriverManager().install()` returned value goes into the `options` parameter.

You don't need `ChromeDriverManager` any more, Selenium 4.10 and newer versions handle the driver versions for you

```
webdriver.Chrome(options=options, seleniumwire_options=proxies)
```