# Python navigate Edge and close automatically

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am navigating through the web with python and downloaded some files. However, I do not want to open edge, just want to download the files, but python opens edge automatically. How do I get around this?

Some of my code include:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Edge()

driver.get("myURL")

time.sleep(2)

id_box = driver.find_element(By.ID,"id")

id_box.send_keys("username")

# And much more...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run Microsoft Edge headless with Selenium Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65171183/how-to-run-microsoft-edge-headless-with-selenium-python)

Comment: What do you mean ` I do not want to open edge, just want to download the files`? You do not want to see the browser, but invisible, headless browser will be OK, or you want the download to be performed with some other tool?

Comment: I have to download multiple files each month, from different websites. Thus I want to open my python program, run the program, and have my files downloaded from edge into respective folders, but I don't want to see multiple tabs of edge open. Edge opening and closing automatically would suffice, but it would be even better to not have to see edge open and close, thus be invisible.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is edge to run `"headless"`.
Didn't find a solution using bare selenium.
There seems to be a solution at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65171416/20443541)