# Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -6

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am using Ubuntu 22.04, and I got this error when I tried to run Selenium tutorial:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -6
```

And this is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Someone can help with the solution? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure, do you have Firefox installed? Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42204897/how-to-set-up-a-selenium-python-environment-for-firefox) thread help for you?

Comment: I have Firefox installed, I read your thread but I don't sure about where to put the geckodriver that I downloaded

Comment: I try this solution but it show me another error. I thinks the reason is because Selenium doesn't work on Ubuntu 22.04 yet.

Comment: I doubt that this is an issue of selenium. Have you tried whether chrome driver works for you?

Comment: Sure. I tried. It worked fine on Windows